# Having problems downloading rancher to my machine

Tags: linux, docker, yaml, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I hope all is well with this pandemic going on. To get to the chase, I'm trying to install rancher on my mac and I've been stuck for the longest at this point. I believe I have everything downloaded properly.  Is there something that I'm missing?

this is running on redhat os linux btw

and this is the command that I am trying to run: ./kubectl -n cattle-system apply -R -f ./rancher

and this is a look at my directory
[image]

Thank You So Much!

```
error validating "rancher/Chart.yaml": error validating data: kind not set; [![enter image description here][1]][1]if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error parsing rancher/templates/clusterRoleBinding.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 6: did not find expected key
error parsing rancher/templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 6: did not find expected key
error parsing rancher/templates/ingress.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 6: did not find expected key
error parsing rancher/templates/issuer-letsEncrypt.yaml: json: line 0: invalid character '{' looking for beginning of object key string
error parsing rancher/templates/issuer-rancher.yaml: json: line 0: invalid character '{' looking for beginning of object key string
error parsing rancher/templates/service.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 6: did not find expected key
error parsing rancher/templates/serviceAccount.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 6: did not find expected key
error validating "rancher/values.yaml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [apple.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the installation instructions for HA here: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/k8s-install/ or for standalone mode here: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/other-installation-methods/single-node-docker/

I guess you have downloaded the rancher helm chart directory and trying to install it using kubectl, which wouldn't work.

Under the HA instructions, you will find the helm install command.